# Breaking out of a loop when a condition occurs, and avoiding the usage of its preset db value 

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, break

Assuming a student take 6 courses in a semester. All those couses have coures units(int), and depending on the score in each course there are points..

```
 so a score >=70 will have a point of 5

 <70 and >=60 will have a ponit of 4
```

and so on. For each course unit and point are multipied together, down the column for each column. Now when the score of a course is not found the grade is 'AR'. Now what i want is for the loops to omit the occurence of AR..i.e not adding the course unit of the course having a grade of 'AR'. But when i run my queries above the units still add to the total course units.

**Query4** is used to generate some rows of **course_unit** and **Score**

```
  $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT  c.course_unit, m.score
  FROM    maintable AS m
  INNER JOIN students AS s ON
  m.matric_no = s.matric_no
  INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
  m.course_code = c.course_code
  WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
  AND m.level = '".$level."'")
  or die (mysql_error());
```

**Query3** is used for the summation of the **course_units**

```
 $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT  SUM(c.
 course_unit) AS 'TOTAL'
 FROM    maintable AS m
 INNER JOIN students AS s ON
 m.matric_no = s.matric_no
 INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
 m.course_code = c.course_code
 WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
 AND m.level = '".$level."'")
 or die (mysql_error());
```

**Grades in Respect to Score**

```
 while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc
 ($query8)) {
            if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
              $grade = 'A';
            }
            elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
               $grade = 'B';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
               $grade = 'C';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
               $grade = 'D';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
               $grade = 'E';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 0) &&
            ($row8['score'] < 40){
               $grade = 'F';
            }else{
               $grade = 'AR';
            }   
     }
```

**Calculation of the Grade Point**

```
      $grade_point = 0;
      while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)) {
         if ($row4['score'] >= 70) {
            $score = 5;
          }
          elseif ($row4['score'] >= 60) {
             $score = 4;
          }elseif ($row4['score'] >= 50) {
             $score = 3;
          }elseif ($row4['score'] >= 45) {
             $score = 2;
          }elseif($row4['score'] >= 40) {
             $score = 1;
          }elseif($row4['score'] >= 0 AND                       $row4['score'] < 40) {
             $score = 0;
          }else{
             $score = 0;
          } 
          
          $grade_point += $score * $row4['course_unit'];
            
      }
```

I have added

```
  if ( $grade == 'AR' )
  {
       continue;
  }
```

But the calculations are still the same. It adds the course_unit  value of any course having

```
$grade == 'AR' .
```

I'll be most delighted with you answers.
Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**

I have being able to solve the grade piont part  by adding

```
     elseif($row4['score'] >= 0 AND                       $row4['score'] < 40) {
             $score = 0;
          }else{
             $score = 0;
          }
```

This sets both the occurences of a score between 0 and 39 to zero and also the default score of  <0 (i.e AR) to zero.
But it still set's the value of the courses having a grade of AR and a score of -1 to the default respective values of the course_unit.

I think this problem is being cause due to the fact that the course_unit are preloaded from the database. Any help?

```
Courses Table Stucture
=================

course_id
course_code
course_title
course_unit
```

I'll be most delighted with your answers.
Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Your question is far too broad and confusing.  Show 1) the actual logic you're asking about and 2) the results of your queries that it's working over and 3) what specifically your question/problem is.

Comment: Assuming a student take 6 courses in a semester. All those couses have course units, and depending on the score in each course there are points..so a score >=70 will have a point of 5, <70 and >=60 will have a ponit of 4 and so on. For each course unit and point are multipied together, down the column for each column. Now when the score of a course is not found the grade is AR. Now what i want is for the loops to omit the occurence of AR i.e not adding the course unit of the course having a grade of 'AR'. But when i run my query above the units still add to the total course units.
Thanks

Comment: I have being able to solve the grade part of the question. By making the grades of both the occurence of grade == 'F' and grade == 'AR' both to zero. But the difference there will be that... Course Unit of a a course having grade 'F', will have their units added to the total course units of all the courses taken by the student, will grades of 'AR' sholdn't. What i'm thinking here could be because, the couses table is preloaded with the course_unit and a called into the loop by default.. But how do i remove the units of courses having a grade of AR from the loop.
Thanks

Comment: `AND NOT m.grade = 'AR'`


So all occurences of AR in the grades column would be omitted.
Thanks a million times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it as simple as adding "AND NOT 'AR'" to your SELECT SUM statement?

Or... if your DB values are coming in as AR, why can't you use PHP is_int() in your loop? That would allow you to still assign 0 for F, and just skip over any non integer values being sent from your DB.

Comment: Indeed your first seggestion was the right answer.


            `AND NOT m.grade = 'AR'`


So all occurences of AR in the grades column would be omitted.
Thanks a million times.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a stab at thee, even though it is difficult to glean what you are trying to accomplish due to some conflicting statements such as; "not adding the **course unit** of the course having a grade of 'AR'", and "But it still set's the value of the courses having a grade of AR and a score of -1 to the default respective values of the **course_unit**."

It seems to me, that query3 is returning a sum of all course_units with no regard to grades or points, so instead of adding, try subtracting, something like:

```
if ( $grade == 'AR' ) {
    // Remove current course_unit from 'Total' derived in query
} 

// Total remains untouched b/c the class was successfully completed
```

Hopefully this makes sense, although the statement you made in your most recent comment; "But when i run my query above the units still add to the total course units", is confusing, because query3 is blindly calculating the total with 0 logic.

Comment: `AND NOT m.grade = 'AR'`


So all occurences of AR in the grades column would be omitted.
Thanks a million times.